# Change SSH key on EC2 Instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to change the SSH key file needed for logging in my Ubuntu EC2 Instance. I know it is not possible to do so directly from the EC2 Management Console so I tried changing it by doing the following:

-Let's call the instance UbuntuA

1. Created a key pair
2. Launched a new Ubuntu Instance (let's call it UbuntuB) using the new key pair
3. Stopped UbuntuA
4. Detached volume `/dev/sda1/` from UbuntuA (Let's call it UbuntuAVolume)
5. Attached UbuntuAVolme to UbuntuB on `/dev/xvdf1`
6. Copied `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` and `/etc/ssh` from UbuntuB to UbuntuAVolume
7. Detached UbuntuAVolume
8. Re-attached UbuntuAVolume to UbuntuA
9. Started UbuntuA

But when I attempt to connect with `putty` I get a `Server refused our key` error message on the terminal and a fatal error popup saying:

Disconnected: No supported authentiction methods available (server sent: public key)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your IP address entry in known_hosts file ?.Also i am assuming that your are connecting with Ubuntu2's private key file

Comment: There is no known_hosts file inside the .ssh directory. And yes I am using the new private key.

Comment: what are the errors in servers `auth.log`?

Comment: error: Received disconnect from {MY IP}: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]